# How to deploy Tonardo web server with python on ubuntu16.04?

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I've built server.py which is responsible for launching server and send the data from csv file to browser with python Tornado web server.
Then I use python command like this.

```
$ python server.py
```

But AttributeError has occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 197, in <module>
    app.autoload.listen(80)
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'autoload'*
```

The server.py is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-# enable debugging 
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PeriodicCallback
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import json
import os
import csv
import sqlite3
..................
args={}
settings = {
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
}
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/cols', ColsHandler),
    (r'/', UploadHandler),
    (r'/conn', ConnHandler)],
    debug=True, **settings)
app.autoload.listen(80)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I don't understand what's going on here.
I would like someone to tell me why this exception is appeared.

Comment: Should it be just `app.listen(80)`?

Comment: I have changed the port from 80 to 15000, but same exception has occured.

Comment: That's not what I mean in my comment. I did not ask you to change port. I asked you to try `app.listen` instead of `app.autoload.listen`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but socket error has occured.
 socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: So, if  you do `app.listen(80)`, the `AttributeError` is gone, but a new error `Permission denied`, right? Now is the time to try another e.g. 8080 or 8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `app.autoload.listen(80)`

should  be written as

```
app.listen(8080)  // or any other port that is not being used
```

Comment: Thanks a million.

Comment: I have changed server.py and it works well. I wanna know the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: No worries. Please kindly accept the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Follow the instructions in the link as I provided in previous comment

Comment: `AttributeError` is due to incorrect use of the `application` object. `Permission denied` due to the fact you try to use port 80 as non-root user (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only)